# Accessing Windows from MacOS (or not)

Tags: finder, network, windows

We just inherited my mother-in-law's Windows 7 HP laptop.  Last time I used Windows was before I retired in 2014 and that was Windows 10.

My MacBook and the HP are on the same 192.168.1.x WiFi and the Mac can ping the HP.  But Finder can't see the HP.  (Yet it still shows my sister's Windows machine—two thousand miles away—which hasn't been reachable in years!)

What do I have to do to get Finder access to files on Windows?  There is an admin account on the HP with no password.  There are five gigabytes of files we need to transfer before we dispose of the HP.  Too slow to transfer that much to iCloud or my website and back.

Second best would be getting Windows to accept connections with rsync, sftp, scp, etc. or installing an APFS driver on Windows.  (I have a portable APFS drive, but it has 4GB already on it that I'd rather not squeeze onto some other drive to allow reformatting this one.)

Comment: Why not just copy the files to a flash drive?

Comment: I don't have a five gigabyte flash drive.  And it turns out to be six, not five.

Comment: This is basically a superuser question. I search and found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/134965/windows-7-not-showing-other-computers-on-network) from 2010.

Comment: idk whether it affects things in this particular case, but there are a lot of things you cannot do on Windows if the admin account has no password, amongst them sign in remotely [or locally for 'repair' functions.]

Comment: Perhaps I should ask on SuperUser.  But that question is not a duplicate.  I don't want Windows to see the Mac.  I wanted the Mac to access the Windows.  I already transferred all her documents, music, videos, etc to my APFS drive, but it would still be nice to know how to add or remove Windows machines from Finder's "network" window.  Which is perhaps also better asked over there.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of fixing this problem might be to make the PC discoverable on the network. I'm sorry, I don't know how to do that but we can do it the other way.

If you open the "Sharing" pane of System Preferences you can select "File Sharing" on the left. This will then allow you to share folder on your Mac. If you click "Options..." you can turn on SMB. If you click on "Edit..." just under the computer name field you can change the name that the Mac advertises.

Once you have done that you should see the Mac in the network from the Windows machine.

The other way is to connect from the Mac using the IP address of the Windows computer. In the Finder under "Go" at the bottom of the menu is "Connect to Server..." select that and enter `smb://192.168.1.1/` replacing the IP address in the example with the IP address of the Windows laptop. This assumes you have shared a folder on the Windows laptop.

Comment: I think your last paragraph might be good enough.  Not going to try it right now, because I am pretty sure "mom" has some malware.  Which presumably can't hurt the Mac, but why tempt fate?

Comment: Good to hear. Let us know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out there is an [APFS driver](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/apfs-windows/) for Windows.  But I'd still like to know how to get Finder access and how to remove my sister's machine from Finder.